# How to benchmark logins per second with omniauth / oauth ? (ruby+rspec)

Tags: ruby, oauth, scalability, benchmarking, omniauth

I want to benchmark how many logins per seconds are possible with an (own) omniauth provider. I need to find out how the performance of this omniauth/oauth requests are, and if this authentication is in anyway scalable?

what I got so far:

```
    def performance_auth(user_count=10)
      bm = Benchmark.realtime do
        user_count.times do |n|
          fork do
            click_on 'Logout'
            omniauth_config_mock(:provider => "foo", :uid => n, :email => "foo#{n}@example.net")
            visit "/account/auth/foo/"
          end
        end
        Process.waitall
      end
      puts "#{user_count} users Benchmark: #{bm}"
      bm
  end
```

the default are 10 users who authenticate parallel through the oauth provider foo.

results:

```
only 2 users can authenticate parallel in 1 sec (is this possible?)

10 users: 5.090777 sec
20 users: 10.471208 sec
50 users: 111.565979 sec ~ 2min!!!!
```

I have really no idea what I'm doing and if this code is right.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have much experience with OAuth/Omniauth, ~500ms render times for this kind of action, when combined with overall Rails (I'm assuming) render times, don't seem that far fetched. IMO, trust your benchmarks.